# How to test/use linkedin post to company page with rest api with admin privilege?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkedin-api

Share/post to company page require us to check if the user is company administrator.

But I am not able to create a company page without a unique working email domain.

How to go about implementing/testing/learning ?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. I know LinkedIn has their own page you can test with, but there's certain API calls you can't make without being a page admin.

Answer (score 2):

There is a test company pages, provider by linked-in team, that all user can post on it:

name: DevTestCo
 id: 2414183

So you can use the endpoint `POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/2414183/shares?format=json` with any user access token.

For more info visit the documentation
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_profile